# program "killed" as soon as it runs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, make, kill, c++

Ubuntu 12.04

I have success with `make`, and output a program name `algo`.
When I type `./algo`,the terminal just directly shows

```
'killed'
```

And I searched the `var/log/message` or `syslog kern.log`. I don't see any information about this kill. And `dmesg` also shows nothing about this.
Then I try 'sudo algo'. There is no output at the terminal and log.
I know there is perhaps an out of memory manager (OOM). But I want to get some information to confirm what happened. What should I do?

Comment: Run it with `strace` tracing ?

Comment: If the OOM-killer terminated it, then there should be some diagnostics logged - normally to `/var/log/syslog`.  Also, that's a likely sign of runaway allocation - did you run your program under `valgrind`?  What is the exit status of your program?  (`echo $?`)  That may help confirm that it terminated due to a signal.  Other possible debug techniques include running under `gdb` and looking to see at what point it crashes (if the signal came from within).

Comment: OK. I'll try what you said. My network meet some problem and I can't log in stackexchange since 8.19. It is work well today. That is why I response to you so late. Thank you very much.